Implement Multiple multilingual sites with same domain followed by country and language code
I need to Implement Multiple multilingual sites with same domain followed by country and language code 2 letters i.e www.abc.com/countrycode-languagecode
Example:

Australia www.abc.com/au-en
France www.abc.com/fr-fr or www.abc.com/fr-en

How do I achieve this with the same hostname and resolve sites based on country and language code? How do I configure the site definition and link manager?

Are you using SXA? Which version of Sitecore? Are you running this in XM Cloud? Please tell us more about your stack.

Non SXA, sitecore 10.3 not on XM cloud.

Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264011/how-to-configure-multilingual-where-language-option-resides-in-request-url-sitec

No there they are are just referiing single multi lingual site. what I am looking for multiple multilingual sites with same hostname.

Just to make sure I understand, let me summarize below: - You have multiple sites, for example one for France, one for Australia, etc. - You would like to access all these sites publicly by using the same domain, but resolving them based on the language code. For example, you have one site for France which is both in English (en-fr) and French (fr-fr). Is this correct?

To clarify, it sounds like you have multiple sites, each corresponding with a specific country. Each country site has one or more languages. You want all sites and their languages to resolve via the same host name, www.abc.com, and then specifically by the country code and language code in the path. Is that correct? Also, which country / language is the default, i.e. what site / language is resolved when only https://www.abc.com/ is requested?
